# Images in web page broken after placing site in a folder

Tags: html

Why did website change when I moved my HTML files into a folder?

On Desktop:
[image: Screenshot of site with images loading properly]

In Folder
[image: Screenshot of site with broken image icons]

Comment: What do you mean. *I folder*?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol r u having fun insulting me ? im just a new to this thing and my english is not that good so i cant properly learn it

Comment: Adrian, did you copy and paste all files inside that Web folder? I assume that you had all the files on your desktop (images and all). You have to copy and paste exactly how they were on the desktop.

Comment: @Ж.Б.Адриан I think the downvotes and the snarky comments were mostly due to the original question title, which assumed that this must be either an "Html bug", or a "coding error", when in fact the real problem was you messing around with something you didn't understand, and also because you haven't shown any effort to solve/understand the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You changed directories and are referencing `/web` in one of them. You will probably need to modify references to images, css files, and any other assets. You can check your browser console for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the screenshots, the website cannot find the image files (probably because you moved the html file to a folder, and the path to the image files is relative from current folder).  Change the path to the files to correspond to where they are actually located, or move the image files to be in the location specified in the paths.